# Cannot get spell check to work

Tags: openoffice.org

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu. Going back at least 3 versions and across updates and re-installations I have never and can still not get open office's spell check to work. This renders the package almost unusable.

So my question is 2 fold:

1)  How can I get the spell check working or is it even possible

2)  What is a good alternative that:

- Has a working spell check
- Converts in a one click process accurately and reliable to pdf

Comment: Are the spell-checking options entirely absent from OpenOffice? Did you install OpenOffice using apt-get? Do you get an error if you try and initiate a spell-check by either keyboard shortcut or the menu item in the Tools menu? In Tools>Options>Language Settings>Languages, do you see a spell-check icon next to the languages in question?

Comment: I ma running the openoffice thatt ships with Ubuntu ASFAIK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Options->Language Settings->Languages` and choose UK or U.S. English. The spell checker is available for only few varieties of English. For e.g. I had selected Indian English once and spell-check was not functioning. If you want to use a third party spell checker, then you can go for this: [After the Dead Line](http://afterthedeadline.com/download.slp?platform=OpenOffice). It is very powerful.

Comment: thanks Nixnotwin, I thought OO.o didn't have this capability at all by itself, I had selected Indian English and I was not working, Now UK English and works fine.

Comment: I had English Philippines set for some reason. Switching to English US worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have never had any troubles with OO. Make sure you have the package `language-support-en` installed (if you need support for other languages, you can find them as `language-support-xx` where xx is the countrycode).

I know these packages install some extra stuff that you might not need (such as interface translations), but they make sure you have all that you need.